# How to copy integer array contents to a character pointer?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have a character pointer , `char *buf;`
I have a array of integers , `int console_buffer[256];`
I need to copy the `console_buffer` contents to character buf. 
How do I do this? The `buf` and `console_buffer` are part of different structures.

Comment: This question is ill-posed. How do you want to convert between int and char?

Comment: I will tell you why I need this. I am trying to implement read system call. The console_buffer is declared as integer array since when EOF is encountered it returns -1, so I know I have to stop here. Actually console_buffer will contain characters. Finally after console_biffer is read, I need to copy it to my Process control block structure which has a char * buf member.

Comment: You can do this with a simple loop. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by your comment,

```
buf = malloc(256); // 257 if console_buffer may be full without EOF
/* if you want to allocate just as much space as needed, locate the EOF in console_buffer first */
for(int i = 0; i < 256 && console_buffer[i] != -1; ++i){
    buf[i] = (char)console_buffer[i];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. My question is since I am storing characters in console_buffer which would be stored as ascii values, will (char)console_buffer[i] convert them back to characters? or do I need  to handle this in different way?

Comment: Yes, casting to `char` does exactly what you want, since what you stored in console_buffer is in the range of `char`. There's a possible problem if `char` is signed, though. The `getc` family returns unsigned `char`s cast to int, these may be out of range for signed `char`, then the conversion is not guaranteed (but it almost certainly does the right thing).

Answer (score 0):

If you already allocated the memory for `buf`, and if each integer is between 0 and 9, you can do:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
{
    buf[i] = '0' + console_buffer[i]; /* convert 1 to '1', etc. */
}
```

If the integers are larger than 9, you can use the [`sprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sprintf/) function.

---

Reading your new comment, perhaps you can also achieve your goal by reading from console buffer directly to an array of chars until you have `-1` (check by integers comparison, or by `strcmp`, or by comparing the 2 last characters to `0` and to `1`).

Comment: Will the following code work?
for(i=0; i< 256; i++){
pcb -> buf = (char*) console_buffer(i);
}
Pardon me if I sound silly , I have just started using pointers, so not yet comfortable with it.

Comment: @Igor Oks: I dont understand. In my console_buffer integer array characters are going to be stored like 'C','I' ... ( I guess the ascii values will be stored am I right? ) and once all is read, -1 integer will be stored at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a better way to convert values to `char`s

```
int i = 0;
while (i <= 256) {
    buf[i] = (char) console_buffer[i];
    i++;
}
```